# Getting null pointer exception when reading from kafka when some of offset is not having any data

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I am reading from kafka topic in spark streaming and job was workign fine until we start getting empty offsets in kafka.

```
[ERROR] org.apache.spark.executor.Executor - Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 12) java.lang.NullPointerException     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.UnsafeWriter.write(UnsafeWriter.java:113)  at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaRecordToUnsafeRowConverter.toUnsafeRow(KafkaRecordToUnsafeRowConverter.scala:39)  at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaMicroBatchInputPartitionReader.next(KafkaMicroBatchReader.scala:339)  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(DataSourceRDD.scala:49)  at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$11$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:619)    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)   at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
```

I tried applying filter on value but as nothing is working
error:

```
  val kafkaDataFrameRaw = spark
    .readStream

    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaUrl)
    .option("subscribe", topics)
    .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", maxOffsetsPerTrigger)
    .option("startingOffsets", startOffsetFinal)
    .option("failOnDataLoss", false)

    .load()


kafkaDataFrameRaw .
    foreachBatch { (result: DataFrame, batchId: Long) =>
     val resultFiltered= result.filter(col("value").isNotNull)
      resultFiltered.show(10,false) }.start()
```

[image]
[image: null pointer exception as soon as calling show in foreachbatch]

[image]
[image]

kafka console consumer :

```
kafka-avro-console-consumer --bootstrap-server kafkabrokernode01:9091,kafkabrokernode01:9091,kafkabrokernode03:9091 --property print.key=true --partition 0 --offset 923390 --max-messages=10 --topic aosdev.tenant_unifiedplanner.plan.digital.lines --property schema.registry.url=http://schemaregurl01:8081

{"id":"{ \"$oid\" : \"6411e90bed84757225eba5d3\"}"}     {"after":null,"patch":null,"source":{"version":{"string":"0.9.5.Final"},"connector":{"string":"mongodb"},"name":"aosdev","rs":"atlas-rnrbpj-shard-0","ns":"tenant_unifiedplanner.plan.digital.lines","sec":1678895535,"ord":31,"h":null,"initsync":{"boolean":false}},"op":{"string":"d"},"ts_ms":{"long":1678895535116}}
{"id":"{ \"$oid\" : \"6411e90bed84757225eba5d3\"}"}     null
{"id":"{ \"$oid\" : \"6411e90bed84757225eba5d4\"}"}     {"after":null,"patch":null,"source":{"version":{"string":"0.9.5.Final"},"connector":{"string":"mongodb"},"name":"aosdev","rs":"atlas-rnrbpj-shard-0","ns":"tenant_unifiedplanner.plan.digital.lines","sec":1678895535,"ord":32,"h":null,"initsync":{"boolean":false}},"op":{"string":"d"},"ts_ms":{"long":1678895535117}}
{"id":"{ \"$oid\" : \"6411e90bed84757225eba5d4\"}"}     null
{"id":"{ \"$oid\" : \"6411e90bed84757225eba5da\"}"}     {"after":null,"patch":null,"source":{"version":{"string":"0.9.5.Final"},"connector":{"string":"mongodb"},"name":"aosdev","rs":"atlas-rnrbpj-shard-0","ns":"tenant_unifiedplanner.plan.digital.lines","sec":1678895535,"ord":33,"h":null,"initsync":{"boolean":false}},"op":{"string":"d"},"ts_ms":{"long":1678895535117}}
```

Comment: When I am using read instead of readstream I am able to filter out  null values but not working when using readstream. Any suggestions please

Comment: The value column is empty. Doesn't mean the key/offset/timestamp columns aren't. Run `result.show()` instead

Comment: Tried that, as soon as I am calling any action on the result df it is throwing null pointer exception .

Comment: Added picture that shows till offset number 923390 job runs fine and as soon as erroneous offset comes it starts throwing null pointer exception

Comment: Can you show `kafka-console-consumer` output with `--offset 923390 --max-messages=10` from whatever partition is failing? Either 1) Debezium/MongoCDC is sending Kafka transaction events, which need skipped anyway 2) The connector is sending tombstone events for delete operations, which you've had to configure it to do 3) Some other process has (mistakenly,/unknowingly) sent bad data into that topic that you're reading, so Spark may have some bug where it cannot print certain events (what version of Spark are you using?). How can we produce this issue ourselves? Ref [mcve]

Comment: @OneCricketeer added some messages, please note this is confluent avro formatted, in case you want to see messages with magic bytes let me know.
I am using aws EMR 5.23 with spark 2.4.0 and scala 2.11.12

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks. So, you realize you are only trying to show dataframes where result value column **is** null? Certainly you want data where **not** null?? Also, Debezium latest version is `2.1.3.Final`, so you may want to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

The offsets are not "empty". You are only trying to print dataframes where the `value` column `isNull`.

I suggest not doing anything with Spark to fix this, however. If you don't want the null values in the Kafka topic at all, set `tombstones.on.delete=false` in  Debezium.

https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/0.9/connectors/mongodb.html

Comment: Updated the filter condition in the question, yes only interested in data where value is not null. I don't have control on debezium connector side so can't update the config there, is there any property in spark side to ignore tombstone records? Or anything else we can do to ignore null value records

Comment: I would try `val resultFiltered = result.na.drop()`

Comment: Tried this before but did not work,
`val kafkaDataFrameRaw1 = spark

      .readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaUrl).option("subscribe", topics)
      .option("truncate", false)
      .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", maxOffsetsPerTrigger).option("startingOffsets", startOffsetFinal)
      .option("failOnDataLoss", false).load()
        .na.drop()

    kafkaDataFrameRaw1.writeStream.format("console").start().awaitTermination()`